# Server 16.04 Update problems

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

New to linux … this is the readout

```
Unpacking util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) over (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to move aside './usr/bin/whereis' to install new version: Structure needs cleaning
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help and reasons would be gratefully received..

Comment: Try to remove problematic deb-package from cache with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb`.

Comment: Tried that and same result and also tried the apt autoremove cmd..

Comment: What is the output of `md5sum /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb`? It should return this MD5 checksum - `cae3d10976f6b124b8bef7bb9cb9bed8` .

Comment: Are you running WSL or normal Ubuntu? What is the output of `apt-cache policy coreutils`?

Comment: checksum returns the required result

Comment: running normal 16.04 server iso

Comment: The policy coreutils returns the following readout  :

Comment: coreutils:
  Installed: 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04
  Candidate: 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04 500
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.25-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Answer (score 0):

I know only one `paste` executable (`/usr/bin/paste`), it is contained in `coreutils` package. You can reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

If it does not help you can try the following.
Usually it is absolutely not recommended but in your rare case I suggest to manually unpack contents of deb package with:

```
sudo dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb /
```

Comment: well that certainly put the machine to bed altogether .. no worries its a virtual machine for the purpose of learning.. returned to a previous state and after starting the process over i am now getting this readout :

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
kms@WebSvr1:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
100 Capabilities
Version: 1.0
Single-Instance: true
Send-Config: true
Local-Only: true
Needs-Cleanup: true
Removable: true

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.